# How to Load and Query data in Druid Timeseries Databases Using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, time-series, druid

I'm new to druid and currently I'm working on a project where data is collected in monthly or weekly basis and further this data is used for some analysis purpose. Currently I'm storing all the data collected in **postgres** with **timestamp** for each row. Now i've decided to go with **timeseries databases(Druid)**, i've gone through the Druid docs and got to know how to load data into Druid through druid console (Basically I exported data into csv from my postgres and loaded that through druid console) and through commands. Now if i want to load and query data using Java how can i do that?.

As I'm not finding much resources regarding this, especially how to load data (in the form of CSV) into druid using Java, it would be very much helpful if someone guide me through this.

Comment: Hi ,Did you found the solution for this ? I am also new to Spring boot and druid . I am looking for code to write Apache druid table as streaming data

Answer (score 0):

You can use druid [client-apis](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#client-apis)
or use [druidry](https://github.com/zapr-oss/druidry)

examples are [here](https://github.com/aamnapm/druid/tree/master)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).